# Are discrete and null graphs the same thing?

Tags: graph-theory

I'm reading Saha Ray's book on graphs, there is a confusion point for me:
on page 5:
**Null graph**: If E = Ø, in a graph G = (V, E), then such a graph without any edges is called a null graph.
on page 14:
**Discrete graph**: A graph is called discrete graph if E(G) = Ø.
**Stable**: X being a subset of V(G) is stable, if G[X] is a discrete graph.
wikipedia: In graph theory, an independent set or stable set is a set of vertices in a graph, no two of which are adjacent. 
These bring me to the following conclusion:
- Discrete means null graph
Is the conclusion correct please?

Comment: From the definitions, it seems that the terms _discrete graph_ and _null graph_ are equivalent. I haven't heard the term "discrete graph" before though. Perhaps you mean "null graph" vs "empty graph" ?

Comment: In the latter case, the distinction depends on the author. The term "empty graph" is used for graphs with $E(G)=\emptyset$ and "null graph" is used to refer particularly to the empty graph with $V(G)=\emptyset$; the terms are also sometimes interchangeably used.